# How do I tell if my container is running inside a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I tell  whether or not I am running inside a kubernetes cluster? With docker I can check if `/.dockerinit` exist. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: I think you can use the kubectl command line tool from kubernetes. [Setup it](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/before-you-begin) run kubectl get pods. you will get list of pods (containers). http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-cheatsheet/

Comment: I want my Golang app To find out programatically.

Comment: You can use kubernetes [client library](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/pkg/client/) to access the kubernetes apis within your code. Sorry, I don't know the exact api name but I think for that you have to read some api doc.

Comment: i just need to set different facebook secrets whenever I am on production or not. Accessing the api for this seems overkill. Think there is another way

Comment: What about this : http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/

Comment: I already got the secrets. I just need to choose which one to use, on each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109219/discussion-between-prtk-shah-and-cesco).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass environment variables to your containers in the pod spec. You can even expose some pod information to the containers via environment variables using the [downward API](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/downward-api/).

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @CESCO I am also trying to detect whether my python code is running on a kubernetes pod, or on my laptop. Is there a way to do this post-hoc without setting up the environment variables in advance?

Answer (score 120):

You can check for `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable.

This variable is always exported in an environment where the container is executed.

Refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#environment-variables

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? Is there a reason this env variable won't be set for a container run by K8s?

Comment: Accepted answer simply means whatever solved the issue that OP asked. It does not in any way indicate which is the most appropriate solution – use votes to determine that.

Answer (score 12):

With the default configuration, Kubernetes will mount the serviceaccount secrets into pods. Simply check for the existence of this folder:  `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io`.
No need to set environment variables. In ruby I would do the following:

```
if File.exists?('/.dockerenv')
  puts "I'm running in a docker container"
end

if File.exists?('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io')
  puts "I'm also running in a Kubernetes pod"
end
```

Comment: Gotta be careful with the service account secret; the token file is usually present but from k8s 1.6 onwards it can be disabled with `automountServiceAccountToken: false`.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said "with the default configuration".

Answer (score 1):

One option is to check the `/etc/hosts` file - there is by default the comment that the file is maintained by K8s.

Anyway the best way is to def your own env variable in deployment, so use some template tools like helm to gen deployment and define some general template.